# local SSH works when using "localhost", but not using IP address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, local-area-network

I'm having difficulty setting up ssh for a laptop on my LAN. I think I have done all the obvious things. On the server:

```
ps -A | grep sshd
18278 ?       00:00:00  sshd
```

and

```
ss -lnp
```

shows sshd listening on port 22. I've checked hosts.deny and hosts.allow, both are empty. UFW show connections allowed on port 22 and the router firewall is turned off.

On the client:

```
ssh -v jane@192.168.2.12                                                                                                   martin@martin-UX21E  7:54PM
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.12 [192.168.2.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 36:bf:c0:c6:d1:e0:16:bd:f0:8c:88:fe:1b:4b:12:74
debug1: Host '192.168.2.12' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection closed by 192.168.2.12
```

On the server,

```
ssh localhost
```

works fine, but

```
ssh 192.168.2.12
```

doesn't. For some reason it is happy to accept connections using the hostname, but not the IP address.

Can anybody suggest the next troubleshooting step?

---

In response to victorcete83:

```
ssh -vvv jane@192.168.2.12                                                                                                 martin@martin-UX21E  8:00PM
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.12 [192.168.2.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.2.12" from file "/home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 36:bf:c0:c6:d1:e0:16:bd:f0:8c:88:fe:1b:4b:12:74
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.2.12" from file "/home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.2.12' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/martin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/martin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
Connection closed by 192.168.2.12
```

Comment: You should check the log files at the server side. Make sure you check `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/daemon.log` for any entries appearing at the time you tried to log in from the client machine.

Comment: How long does it take from pressing Enter after `ssh -v jane@192.168.2.12` to `Connection closed by 192.168.2.12`? 10 second? Maybe 30?

Comment: Can you try connecting with more verbosity and take a look? `ssh -vvv jane@192.168.2.12`

Comment: two minutes exactly (measured using time())

Comment: running tail on /var/log/auth.log doesn't show anything when I try to log in. I don't have a /var/log/daemon.log.

Comment: As Cedric said, you need to provide what the log file says in the ssh server. check `/etc/syslog.conf` and find the log files associated with `authpriv`. Then please post the contents of that files, most likely /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 1):

If the ssh connection **works** pointing to localhost, means that it's going to 127.0.0.1. If it **fails** with pointing to 192.168.2.12 should be because your ssh is listening on 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Check your `ListenAddress` on sshd configuration file.

Comment: Connection to 192.168.2.12:22 establishes, it is clear from debug messages. Localhost connection succeeds because of faster local authentication - it fits the `LoginGraceTime` period.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to run the sshd deamon manually on the server with the `-d` flag to generate more debug output on the server. it will stay in the foreground and output debut information on the console.

You can run this second sshd deamon in parallel on another port using the `-p <portnumber>` option when you start the second deamon.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh'ing from another lan host to your laptop.  My guess is your .ssh directory has some mangled or mismatched keys in it.  Starting on another host eliminates the .ssh directory contents other than authorized_keys from being the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two minutes is too long. I am sure your `sshd` closes connection because of settings in `sshd_config`. Check `LoginGraceTime` in `sshd_config`. It is exactly 120 seconds by default. Try to set 300 seconds and then try to connect.
To fasten the authentication, turn off unused authentication methods. In case you want only Password and Pubkey auth, set `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `no`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command from your terminal:

```
sudo ufw app list
```

If you get the line:

```
Available applications:
  ...
  OpenSSH
  ...
```

then you should run

```
sudo ufw allow 'OpenSSH'
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> debug1: Connection established.

If you are seeing this when connecting from a remote client then you appear to have completed the TCP handshake. That makes it exceedingly unlikely that there is a problem with TCP wrappers, the firewall or the listenaddress in the sshd_config.

> Roaming not allowed by server

While this looks like the reason for the failure, it relates to previously undocumented feature in openssh which in a normal installation is informational only (and recently discovered to [expose a vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-0777) if the default config is modified).

The server is choosing to terminate the connection, so that's where you should be looking to find out why. Set LogLevel=DEBUG in your sshd config (and amend your syslog config to record at that level).