# ssh to localhost works but remote connection does not

Tags: ssh

I'm having trouble ssh-ing to my computer. `ssh localhost` works fine. But when I use this site: http://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php to check my remote connection, it doesn't work. (I think the site is working because I've used it with success in the past). I've fiddled around with the `ssh_config`, `sshd_config`, and checked the ssh logs but can't figure out what to try next. Any thoughts?

(These haven't helped:
[local SSH works when using "localhost", but not using IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/481249/local-ssh-works-when-using-localhost-but-not-using-ip-address?rq=1))

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to ssh remotely?

Comment: none i dont see anything in auth.log -- like failed attempts or anything

Comment: Ok and I assume port 22 is open if you can connect locally? (`netstat --listen`)

Comment: that interesting, `netstat` shows `localhost:11211` but `sshd_config` is listening on 22. I tried changing the port number on the website above and connecting, but it didn't work

Comment: Please post (redacted for security) sshd_config file and/or the output of netstat --listen.

Comment: @CatherineMacInnes http://pastebin.com/hxV9GLaD

Comment: What is the FQDN and IP address of your computer? When you use the ssh server test website what are you entering into the dialog box?

Comment: I use the outputs on this website: http://www.infobyip.com/whatismyip.php

Comment: It's likely that you have a firewall performing network address translation outbound but not inbound, so the site in the question is unable to connect to your computer. You would need to provide more information to know for sure. Specifically the IP address assigned to your computer as output from `ifconfig` command and the output from the what is my ip website.

Comment: in `ifconfig` i get 3 entries for `inet6 addr` one of them matches the website, the other two dont. Two of them have `Scope:Global` and one has `Scope:Local` (one with `Scope:Global` matches the website's IP) -- what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firewall is blocking the communication.  Since you can SSH to localhost, the service is up and running and it is on the correct port.  There is not a problem with the service or sshd config.

Depending on the linux flavor you are using:

Red Hat / Centos run - **service iptables stop**

Debian / Ubuntu - look here:  http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=112759

If after you run through that, you test and it works, then you will need to open a port on your firewall.

This does not take into account hardware routers/firewalls that you may have from your internet provider.